# NSPopover in HUD mode blurs - but NSWindow in HUD does not

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nspopover

Is there a way to either blur the NSWindow in HUD mode or unblur the NSPopover so that the effect matches?

[image]

Comment: How about the `applyGaussianBlurWithRadius:` method from https://github.com/alunbestor/Boxer/blob/master/Other%20Sources/ADBToolkit/NSWindow%2BADBWindowEffects.m

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [GitHub project](https://github.com/dsns/GaussianBlur_NSWindow_os_x_mavericks). It looks like crutch code
but it works.